# WRITE_ONCE in linux kernel lists

Tags: c, linux, macros, race-condition

I am reading the [linux kernel implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) of doubled linked list. I do not understand the use of the macro `WRITE_ONCE(x, val)`. It is defined as follow in compiler.h:

```
#define WRITE_ONCE(x, val) x=(val)
```

It is used seven times in the file, such as

```
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    WRITE_ONCE(prev->next, new);
}
```

I have read that it is used for avoiding race conditions.

I have two questions:
1/ I thought macro was replace by code at compile time. So how this code differs to the following one ? How this macro can avoid race conditions ?

```
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    prev->next = new;
}
```

2/ How to know when we should use it ? For instance, it is used for `__lst_add()` but not for `__lst_splice()`:

```
static inline void __list_splice(const struct list_head *list,
                 struct list_head *prev,
                 struct list_head *next)
{
    struct list_head *first = list->next;
    struct list_head *last = list->prev;

    first->prev = prev;
    prev->next = first;

    last->next = next;
    next->prev = last;
}
```

edit:
Here is a commit message concerning this file and `WRITE_ONCE`, but it does not help me to understand anything...

> **list: Use WRITE_ONCE() when initializing list_head structures**
>   Code that does lockless emptiness testing of non-RCU lists is relying
>   on INIT_LIST_HEAD() to write the list head's ->next pointer
>   atomically, particularly when INIT_LIST_HEAD() is invoked from
>   list_del_init(). This commit therefore adds WRITE_ONCE() to this
>   function's pointer stores that could affect the head's ->next pointer.

Comment: Not sure, but looking at [compiler.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/compiler.h#L294) line 294 the definition is longer and uses `__write_once_size`...

Comment: Yep, there is several definitions of `WRITE_ONCE` (it is defined in three headers), I do not known exactly which one is used...

Comment: Have you read [this comment](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/include/linux/compiler.h#L115) about their purpose? Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it helps me to understand a bit deeper. I still do not understand the mechanism which avoid the compiler to fold instructions. Does that means that the compiler optimizes code before replacing macro ?

Comment: I'll put an answer together.

Comment: @Gaut When you say "race condition", do you mean data race?

Comment: @Shakkhar: I do

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The first definition you refer to is part of the [kernel lock validator](https://lwn.net/Articles/185666/), aka "lockdep". `WRITE_ONCE` (and others) don't need special treatment, but the reason why is the subject of another question.

The relevant definition would be [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/include/linux/compiler.h#L115), and a very terse comment states their purpose to be:

> Prevent the compiler from merging or refetching reads or writes.
>
> ...
>
> Ensuring that the compiler does not fold, spindle, or otherwise mutilate accesses that either do not require ordering or that interact with an explicit memory barrier or atomic instruction that provides the required ordering.

But what do those words mean?

---

## The problem

The problem is actually plural:

1. Read/write "tearing" : replacing a single memory access with many smaller ones. GCC may (and does!) in certain situations replace something like `p = 0x01020304;` with two 16-bit store-immediate instructions -instead of presumably placing the constant in a register and then a memory access, and so forth. `WRITE_ONCE` would allow us to say to GCC, "don't do that", like so: `WRITE_ONCE(p, 0x01020304);`
2. C compilers have stopped guaranteeing that a word access is atomic. Any program which is non-race-free can be [miscompiled](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf) with spectacular results. Not only that, but a compiler may decide to *not* keep certain values in registers inside a loop, leading to multiple references that can mess up code like this:

```
    for(;;) {
        owner = lock->owner;
        if (owner && !mutex_spin_on_owner(lock, owner))
            break;
        /* ... */
    }
```

3. In absence of "tagging" accesses to shared memory, we *cannot* automatically detect unintended accesses of that sort. Automated tools that try to [find such bugs](https://github.com/google/kernel-sanitizers/blob/master/other/READ_WRITE_ONCE.md) cannot distinguish them from intentionally racy accesses.

---

## The solution

We begin by noting that the Linux kernel demands to be built with GCC. Thus, there's only one compiler we need to take care of with the solution, and we can use its [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html) as the only guide.

For a generic solution, we need to handle memory accesses of all sizes. We have all the various types of specific widths, and everything else. We also note that we don't need to specifically tag memory accesses which are already in critical sections (*why not?*).

For sizes of 1, 2, 4, and 8 bytes, there are appropriate types, and `volatile` specifically disallows GCC from applying the optimisation we referred to in (1), as well as taking care of [other cases](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) (last bullet point under "COMPILER BARRIERS"). It also disallows GCC of miscompiling the loop in (2), because it would move the `volatile` access across a sequence point, and that's disallowed by the C standard. Linux [uses](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/include/linux/compiler.h#L62) what we call a "volatile access" (see below) instead of tagging an object as volatile. We *could* solve our problem by marking the specific object as `volatile`, but this is (almost?) never a good choice. There are [many](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.2/source/Documentation/process/volatile-considered-harmful.rst) [reasons](https://lwn.net/Articles/233482/) it could be harmful.

This is how a volatile (write) access is implemented in the kernel for an 8-bit wide type:

```
*(volatile  __u8_alias_t *) p = *(__u8_alias_t  *) res;
```

Suppose we didn't know *exactly* what `volatile` does - and finding out [isn't easy!](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/28) (check out #5) - another way to accomplish this would be to place memory barriers: This is exactly what Linux does in case the size is anything other than 1,2,4, or 8, resorting to `memcpy` and placing memory barriers before *and* after the call. Memory barriers easily solve problem (2) as well, but incur large performance penalties.

I hope I've covered an overview without delving into interpretations of the C standard, but if you'd like I could take the time to do that.

Comment: what's the meaning of "Not only that, but a compiler may decide to not keep certain values in registers inside a loop, leading to multiple references that can mess up code like this". push out and pull back some register have problem?

Comment: @Jams.Liu it means `owner = lock->owner;` could be read _outside_ the loop body.