# if struct and its contained structs are not made of primivitive types, the how size get evaluated. How to use it correct way

Tags: c

If I have a struct like

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

so I like to know what is the point of this struct?

what `next` and `priv` can contain. since its a pointer. I really don't know its size

if I have simple code like below

```
struct list_head 
{
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
} *p,v;
printf("%lu %lu %lu ...",sizeof(p),sizeof(*p),sizeof(v));
```

the output shows

8 16 16 .

but the thing I am confused with is how I can use the struct. What I will assigned to it

Up until now I was under the impression that we do and must need primitive types to define a type. For example this makes sense

```
struct a{
    int *x;
    char b[100];
 };
 struct b{
    struct a *p;
   }
```

so in above struct the child contains primitive types. In what way I get the output of my first program `8 16 16 ...` how my struct got even evaluated. is there anything I am missing? p is pointer but how 8 is printed? who defined the size of `struct a` to be 8 Obviously I didn't.

Also how to use my first example struct

this one

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

Comment: this code is found in kernel in napi_struct and other places. napi_struct struct contains object of this struct .Linux kernel to be more specific

Comment: `p` is a pointer, `*p` is a structure containing two pointers. Pointers are 8 bytes, so 2 pointers are 16 bytes.

Comment: @user786 Read a book for beginners about linked lists.

Comment: @Barmar how can I assign value to p and member what value what type 1 'a' 1.1 these are int char float type values so gcc and C understands it. What I will assigned to it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just asking for applicability of this link list what type of data it will hold?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can I assign any variable or object address to `p` which and whose members can be accessed by 8 bytes sized of pointer?

Comment: @user786 The structure can be a first member of any other structure. So it can be used to link data in a list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can that data be like `struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev; int x;
};` so x will hold the data? am I getting it?

Comment: @user786 You can do what you like.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can I maintain linked List of  of packets maintained like list of iphdr and data. and access it in some application from userspace?.

Comment: @user786 If you have questions you can ask them at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Linux kernel list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h).

It is dedicated to be placed inside a struct as a member.

Typically there is one object that "owns" the head of list and the children objects that owns list node:

```
struct parent {
  int a;
  struct list_head head;
};

struct child {
  int a;
  struct list_head node;
  int b;
};
```

New elements are added using `list_add` function:

```
struct parent p;
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&p.head);
struct child c1, c2;
list_add(&c1.node, &p.head);
list_add(&c2.node, &p.head);
```

Elements can remove themself from the list with `list_del`. For example `c2` could remove itself from the list with:

```
list_del(&c2.node);
```

The typical iteration over list would be:

```
struct parent *p = ...;
for (struct list_head *n = p->head.next; p != &p->head; p = p->next) {
   struct child *c = list_entry(p, struct child, node);
   ... do stuff with c ...
}
```

Note that `list_entry` is used to convert a pointer to struct member to the pointer to parenting struct. It is a wrapper around `container_of` macro which is **not** strictly conforming. So it should be used with care.

---

EDIT

The Linux implementation of lists is quite complex. Below one can find a simpler implementation:

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>

struct list {
    struct list *next, *prev;
};

static inline void list_add(struct list *node, struct list *head)
{
    node->next = head->next;
    node->prev = head;
    head->next->prev = node;
    head->next = node;
}

static inline void list_del(struct list *node)
{
    node->next->prev = node->prev;
    node->prev->next = node->next;
}

#define list_entry(ptr,type,member) \
    ((type*)(((char*)ptr) - offsetof(type,member)))

static inline void list_init(struct list *node)
{
    node->next = node;
    node->prev = node;
}

#define DEFINE_LIST(name) struct list name = { .next = &name, .prev = &name }

#define LIST_FOREACH(it,head) \
    for (struct list *it = (head)->next; it != (head); it = it->next)
```

Comment: What is `node` parameter to list_entry function. What is the data type of third parameter. Is this object or what is it?

Comment: What is the WRITE_ONCE(prev->next, new); it's in the implementation of list that u mentioned a link of source header file. Can u please tell me this?

Comment: @user786, WRITE_ONCE is used for a very technical reasons related to correct multithreading for optimizing compilers. You can find details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988277/write-once-in-linux-kernel-lists. I've attached a simplified version of `list` interface to the answer. I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't hold any data by itself. It's used as a substructure in other structures, e.g.

```
struct offset {
    struct list_head list;
    unsigned offset;
};
```

This makes `offset` a doubly-linked list.

They could have done it by including a generic data pointer in the `list_head` structure:

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
    void *data;
};
```

But this would waste memory with an extra pointer, and it's also less efficient because there will be frequent cache misses when you have to follow the pointer. Putting the links directly in the structure avoids these problems.

Comment: but `list_head` already has two pointers. haven't they still wasted memory `But this would waste memory with an extra pointer,` please clarify

Comment: Those pointers are necessary to make a linked list.

Comment: The point is to not add any extra pointers between the list nodes and the data.